Dropdown bar hidden behind another element
I am new to CSS and I wanted to make dropdown bar. I looked at some tutorial on youtube, and I implemented it on my code. It went well until I make a new section element, my dropdown bar is now hidden behind the element, what should I do to fix this?


:root {
  --color-1: #ff8787;
  --color-2: #475569;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-2);
  background: #ddd;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-2);
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-middle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.login {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;

  background: #ddd;
  color: var(--color-2);
  height: 500px;
}

.nav-middle li:hover .menu-sub,
.nav-middle li:active .menu-sub {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-sub a {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.35em;
}

.menu-sub a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu-category {
  margin: 2.5rem 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-category:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu-col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.menu-sub-left {
  background-color: #7950f2;

  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.menu-sub ul {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

/* Showcase */
.showcase {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  columns: var(--color-2);
  position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.showcase .showcase-text div {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Utilities */
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #845ef7;
  color: var(--color-2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #7950f2;
}

.btn-outline {
  background-color: #ff8787;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-2);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container flex">
        <h1 class="logo">AcademyOfCode</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-middle">
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Catalog <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div class="menu-col-1">
                  <div class="menu-sub-left">
                    <h3 class="menu-category">Course recommendations</h3>
                    <p>Explore our paid or free courses</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Python</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Html</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SQL</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">C++</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Java</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">C#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">R</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Pricing <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">For students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For individuals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For teams</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Community <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Discord</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-right">
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-outline" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section class="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="showcase-text">
          <h1>AcademyOfCode empowers you to build tech fluency</h1>
          <p>Build your tech skill here with CodeOfAcademy</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline">Learn to Code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>



I have tried to put a height on menusub class and set the overflow to auto, but it doesn't change anything

use z-index for .menu-sub

You can use z-index css property, set the value higher than other.
.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;

  background: #ddd;
  color: var(--color-2);
  height: 500px;
  
  z-index: 1; /* Magic is here */
}

More about z-index


:root {
  --color-1: #ff8787;
  --color-2: #475569;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-2);
  background: #ddd;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-2);
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-middle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.login {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;

  background: #ddd;
  color: var(--color-2);
  height: 500px;
  
  z-index: 1; /* Magic is here */
}

.nav-middle li:hover .menu-sub,
.nav-middle li:active .menu-sub {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-sub a {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.35em;
}

.menu-sub a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu-category {
  margin: 2.5rem 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-category:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu-col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.menu-sub-left {
  background-color: #7950f2;

  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.menu-sub ul {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

/* Showcase */
.showcase {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  columns: var(--color-2);
  position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.showcase .showcase-text div {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Utilities */
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #845ef7;
  color: var(--color-2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #7950f2;
}

.btn-outline {
  background-color: #ff8787;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-2);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container flex">
        <h1 class="logo">AcademyOfCode</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-middle">
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Catalog <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div class="menu-col-1">
                  <div class="menu-sub-left">
                    <h3 class="menu-category">Course recommendations</h3>
                    <p>Explore our paid or free courses</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Python</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Html</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SQL</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">C++</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Java</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">C#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">R</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Pricing <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">For students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For individuals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For teams</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Community <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Discord</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-right">
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-outline" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section class="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="showcase-text">
          <h1>AcademyOfCode empowers you to build tech fluency</h1>
          <p>Build your tech skill here with CodeOfAcademy</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline">Learn to Code</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>



